# NXP NFC NDEF Tag memory size issue

Tags: java, android, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

I am using NXP NDEF tag and NFC Tag writer app given by NXP but in sony phone app show memory 524 byte but in MOTO mobile show as 52 byte memory. I am finding solution more than time but not resolved it. Please help me find out it.

I use the following code to read memory:

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
int maxlength=ndef.getMaxSize();
```

For writing data I use

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", byteArray);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(mimeRecord);
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

int maxlength=ndef.getMaxSize();
Here, ndef.getMaxSize response depends on the Ndef object returned by the Android Middleware. Due to the changes in one android middleware to another, there is a possibility that it returns unexpected object with discrepancy in the values like maxSize.
NXP provides a Open API library for Java and Android app development called "TapLinx" which is free to use. For better results you can use that.
Hope the info helps. Cheers!